# Coding a rainy cloud in CSS

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

I want to code a rainy cloud and I am new in CSS. 
Could anyone help me? I made the cloud and raindrops with inkscape, but they don't do what they should do.

- I don't know how to use 2 classes for 1 image.

```css
.hovering {
  animation-name: hovering;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes hovering {
  from {
    transform: translate(0, 0px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(0, -25px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translate(0, -0px);
  }
}

.rain-cloud .raindrop-1,
.rain-cloud .raindrop-2,
.rain-cloud .raindrop-3 {
  opacity: 0;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(1, 0, 1, 1);
}

.rain-cloud .raindrop-1 {
  animation: falling-drop-1 2s infinite;
}

.rain-cloud .raindrop-2 {
  animation: falling-drop-2 1.90s infinite;
  animation-delay: 0.8s;
}

.rain-cloud .raindrop-3 {
  animation: falling-drop-3 1.80s infinite;
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
}

@keyframes falling-drop-1 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-35px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  10% {
    transform: translateY(-15px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  30% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  60% {
    transform: translateY(100px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-35px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes falling-drop-2 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-105px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  10% {
    transform: translateY(-85px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  30% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  60% {
    transform: translateY(5px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-105px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes falling-drop-3 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-105px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  10% {
    transform: translateY(-85px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  30% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  60% {
    transform: translateY(35px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-105px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="weather rainy"></div>
<svg class="rain-cloud">
  <img src="cloudGrey.svg" class="hovering" width="150" height="150"/>
  <img src="raindrop1.svg" class="raindrop-1" width="40" height="40"/>
  <img src="raindrop2.svg" class="raindrop-2" width="40" height="40"/>
  <img src="raindrop3.svg" class="raindrop-3" width="40" height="40"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: an idea for the rain: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59922255/8620333 and another one for the cloud: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59339759/8620333

Comment: Thank you, I will check them